# Mathematically-based online games

Tags: reference-request, education, online-resources

I am looking for online games or puzzles which have a mathematical flavor and are suitable for general audiences. A classical example is the online version of [Set Card Game](http://www.setgame.com/set/). Or [this game](https://www.increpare.com/2011/01/catalan/) that has some aspects of graphs.

[A related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73975/exciting-games-and-material-to-motivate-children-to-math?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm very interested in these as well as physics games. I think they are accessible ways to get students or citizens involved in doing mathematics as mathematicians do it.  The following are some of what I have found and collected online with eye towards encouraging reasoning. Stack Exchange wouldn't let me post too many links here, so I collected them in a Tumblr post: https://mathhombre.tumblr.com/post/45269554617/online-games-with-some-math-content

Traditional: Minesweeper and Lights Out.

New, in rough order of how much I like them.

Love:

- Entanglement
- Grow
- Animal Mazemaker

Like:

- Refraction
- Loops of Zen
- hexxagon
- Paths
- Stepping Stones
- Z-Rox

I'll also mention Robert Abbott's lovely logic mazes, https://www.logicmazes.com/

Answer (score -1):

Poker has some serious mathematical aspects, so I think online poker qualifies.

Comment: This question was flagged as it can be a comment, but maybe it is of high quality to let it stay as an answer.

Comment: @ТymaGaidash Actually, this was meant as a serious answer (not a comment). There are several places where you can play online poker, and it is a game of probability (and hence math).